# Update Command with Case in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

I want to update table `A` in such a way that if the attribute of the table column is desired then only it will change otherwise it wont change..

```
Update table A set B="abcd" ,C= (case when C="abc" then C="abcd" else C end) where column =1;
```

means `C` should be only change when in `column=1 and C value is abc`  otherwise `C` should not be update ..it should be dropped and only `B` changes. but if the `C`
 value get matched i.e abc give me the output 0 .. not changing to the abcd

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Inside the `THEN` part, `C="abcd"` compares `C` with the value, and returns either 1 or 0.

The entire `CASE` expression should just *return* a value that then gets written into the `C` column, so you want just `'abcd'` in this place:

```
UPDATE tableA
SET B = 'abcd',
    C = CASE
        WHEN C = 'abc' THEN 'abcd'
                       ELSE C
        END
WHERE column = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to do two separate things:

```
UPDATE A set B = 'abcd' WHERE column = 1

UPDATE A set C = 'abcd' WHERE C = 'abc' AND column = 1
```

Is that right? If so, can you do it as two simple statements instead of one complicated statement?

Comment: if I will create the separate table there will be huge work for me..isn't possible to make change as I was trying

Comment: It's not a separate *table*, it's a separate *statement*.

Comment: ya sorry ...statement...isnt it possible by any way which i am trying